# Linked Cluster Theorem in Conformal Field Theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I am trying to compute an effective action for the source fields $J(x)$ in some theory $$S=S_\mathrm{CFT} + S_J= S_\mathrm{CFT} + \int \phi^\ast J + h.c. $$ where $\phi$ is a primary of my (interacting) CFT, where I use Operator Product Expansions (OPEs) of the $\phi$ fields to reduce $$\langle \phi_a^\ast(x) \phi_b(y) \rangle_\mathrm{CFT} = \delta_{ab} 1/(x-y)^{2 \Delta}.$$ Let us further assume that there is another primary $\theta$ in the OPE $$\phi_a^\ast \times \phi_b \sim \delta_{ab} + \theta_c f^c_{ab}.$$

I am curious about higher order terms in the expansion -- in standard QFT, the linked cluster theorem guarantees that the effective action $$S_\mathrm{eff} = -\log Z = -\log Z_\mathrm{CFT} + 1/2 \langle S_J^2 \rangle_\mathrm{CFT} + 1/24 (\langle S_J^4 \rangle_\mathrm{CFT} -3 \langle S_J^2 \rangle_\mathrm{CFT}^2)$$ (dropping a few vanishing terms) should only contain connected diagrams (by which I mean terms with a "double-OPE" involving the $\theta$ fields, e.g. at quartic order) which is easily verified by expanding $Z$ and using Wick's theorem. On the other hand, using the OPE, I am "selecting" a pair of operators to be replaced by a propagator, rather than summing over all possible contractions. Does this mean that the linked cluster theorem is not applicable for my OPE procedure?

As an example, consider the "disconnected" parts in the quartic term (schematic notation) $$<S_J^4>_\mathrm{CFT} \sim  (1+1^\ast)(2+2^\ast)(3+3^\ast)(4+4^\ast) = \dots + 6 G^2 + \dots$$ (where $G$ denotes the propagator) which is **not** canceled by $$3 <S_J^2>_\mathrm{CFT}^2 = 12 G^2.$$

I would be grateful if anyone could clarify if there is an analogue to the linked cluster theorem in CFT/how Wick's theorem and OPEs relate.

**EDIT:**
Here, I take $\langle \cdot \rangle_\mathrm{CFT}$ to refer to the expectation value with respect to the CFT action, i.e. $\langle \mathcal{O} \rangle_\mathrm{CFT} = \frac{1}{Z_\mathrm{CFT}} \int \mathcal{D}[\dots] \mathcal{O} e^{-S_\mathrm{CFT}}$ and $Z = \int \mathcal{D}[\dots] e^{-S}$ with $S$ given above, allowing for the perturbative expansion in $J$. $S^n_J$ refers to $(S_J)^n$ etc.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this is deep question.

Comment: A pedantic request to define what you mean by $S_J$ and $S_J^n$, as well as what you mean by $\langle\cdot\rangle$. Do you mean expectation value with respect to a free theory or with respect to the full interacting theory? A less pedantic reasoning for the above: If you are around the interacting theory how do you integrate out $\phi$? If you are around some free limit, integrating out $\phi$ will yield something very non-local for $J$, since $\phi$ is massless (due to conformal invariance).

Comment: Hi @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, I have made a few edits that should clarify what I mean by the various terms. I am integrating out with respect to the CFT fixed point using the OPEs. I agree that the induced terms for $J$ will be highly non-local and I am willing to accept this for now …

Comment: Doesn't associativity of the OPE imply that your "choice" of pairs actually doesn't matter, so you end up picking up all pairs anyway (up to associativity identities on the coefficient).

Comment: Hi @RichardMyers, that's right! Initially I had been thinking to truncate the OPE at the primary (i.e. not thinking about the descendants), which would only keep one choice of pairs, I think. The other pairs/singularities would be hidden in the expansion … See also my related question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675280/