# How do Wick contractions and OPEs relate?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I am trying to understand how to recover the factorisation of the four-point function (assume $\langle \phi\rangle = 0$) of some free Gaussian field $$\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \phi(x_3) \phi(x_4) \rangle = \langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle \langle \phi(x_3) \phi(x_4) \rangle +\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_3) \rangle \langle \phi(x_2) \phi(x_4) \rangle  +\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_4) \rangle \langle \phi(x_2) \phi(x_3) \rangle$$ with $\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle= 1/(x_1-x_2)^{2 \Delta}$ within a conformal field theory framework. My understanding is that I should be able to use the operator product expansion $\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \sim \langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle + \dots$ whenever I can draw a sphere around $x_1$ and $x_2$ without encountering any other operator insertions. I am willing to consider an integrated version of this (i.e. integrate over $x_1, \dots x_4$ and then split up the integral in appropriate ways, but I am unsure how to make this work precisely. Any help or references are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Besides the identity, the $\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$ OPE contains exactly one primary operator for each non-negative integer $n$. The spin of each one is $2n$ while the scaling dimension is $2\Delta + 2n$. Are you looking for explicit OPE coefficients such that the infinitely many contributions resum to the expression you wrote above? These can certainly be looked up. But they were of course derived by *assuming* that correlators factorise as this is the abstract definition of a free theory.

Comment: Ah, so I really need to think about the full resummation (do you have a good reference on that?) I was hoping I could split the space of relative coordinates into different configurations to extract the leading singular behaviour (without having to think about *all* primaries), similar to how (3.28) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04444 is treated? This question is an attempt to get an idea how this problem: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674533/  might be treated. Would appreciate any thoughts/comments!

Comment: Oh yes, if you're integrating a four-point function, then splitting the domain into three regions and using a different OPE channel in each one is the most efficient way. But after David and Zohar consider relevant operators to solve for the counter-terms, they also add as many irrelevant operators as they can.

If it helps, https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0151 is the paper I was thinking of with explicit expansions.

Comment: I am a bit stuck with translating David and Zohar's approach to my problem: I get that I can eliminate one coordinate by translational invariance but I do not see why it is sufficient for me to consider one operator to be located at infinity (after all, this implies it will never be "close" to the other operators?). Do you think in this approach, I would eventually be able to obtain $\int d^dx d^dy d^dz d^dw G^{(4)}(x,y,z,w) = 3 (\int d^dx d^dy G^(2)(x,y))^2$?, where $G^(n)$ denotes the n-point function?

Comment: What you wrote just looks like an exact identity for the free theory. But indeed, they are using some tricks. Namely the fact that conformal transformations can bring four operators at arbitrary positions to $x_1 = 0, x_3 = e_1, x_4 = \infty$.

Comment: You can find the OPE with lots of gory combinatorial details in Section 6 of my article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-019-03665-4 However it is a very raw OPE where there is no representation theory and no grouping of the fields in conformal multiplets. For that you might want to consult https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP10(2019)217

Comment: @ConnorBehan: Yes, I used what I know about the free theory to write this identity down. But I do not see how to recover this by splitting up coordinate space into the various regions and using the OPE in there, because even using their trick the integrals would only cover some part of coordinate space (e.g. valid only for $r_{12}< r_{23},r_{13}$), whereas the integrals on the RHS extend over all x,y …

Comment: If you believe that the infinite OPEs (12)(34), (13)(24) and (14)(23) all reproduce the $s + t + u$ sum you wrote then it's immediate that this would also hold under the integral sign.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your bountied question but it seems that the most solid way to establish a relation between Wick's theorem and the free OPE is the following: 1. Assume factorization of 4pt functions. 2. Use this to derive all OPE coefficients in $\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$. 3. Show that iterative use of this OPE in a 6pt or higher function is still compatible with factorisation.

Comment: Hi @ConnorBehan, thanks for your comments. I still don't understand how the choice of coordinates works in general. I have $\int d^dx_1 d^d x_2 d^dx_3 d^dx_4 G^{(4)}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Your mapping and also the choice of David and Zohar corresponds to putting one of the coordinates (say, x_4) to $+\infty$ which seems to imply that the other operators can never get close to that particular operator and thus we are "missing" this divergence in the integration? Maybe I am being daft.